# Desktop Cannot Ping Website, While Phone, Using Same WiFi, can Load it

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, ping

I'm using Windows 10 Pro and when I ping www.grasshopper3d.com every package gets lost.

My phone, using the same wifi, has no problem to load, also, when requesting the desktop site...

I have no clue what that is telling me. Any hints?

Comment: Check your dns settings? For instance can you ping 208.82.16.68? which is the IP from grasshopper3d.com

Comment: No, times out, too. My 'hosts' file is also empty. And trying to load the mobile site from my desktop also fails.

Comment: Does this happen on every website or just the one?

Comment: This is the only I know of. It happens with all installed browsers (latest FF Edge, IE). And I also tried 'Netsh winsock reset'.

Comment: Can you try a tracert to grasshopper3d.com?

Comment: Yeah, result is here: http://hastebin.com/opiruneyow.css

Comment: Well it could be anything at this point. Maybe its the browser blocking the website, maybe its your anti-virus, Firewall could be a thing aswell.

Comment: No, turning off Firewall and Windows Defender doesn't work, either. And it's in all browsers. So that's not the reason. Annoying...

Comment: Well I think if its only on that certain website they are filtering your mac-address probably. meaning your device is kinda banned from their website.